# Webpack Compilation Cannot read property 'semaphore' of null

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg

Trying to build my React app and I am having this compilation error:

```
/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:268
                                                _this.semaphore.release();

TypeError: Cannot read property 'semaphore' of null
at factoryCallback (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:268:12)
at factory (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20)
at resolver (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
at asyncLib.parallel.e (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
at /Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3861:9
at /Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
at iteratorCallback (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:996:13)
at /Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
at /Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3858:13
at resolvers.normal.resolve (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
at onError (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:65:10)
at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
at runAfter (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
at innerCallback (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
at next (/Users/jimvercoelen/Documents/bitbucket/inboundmuse-client/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
```

And I have no clue what's causing this issue. It looks like I am the only one facing this when I try googles help..

Answer (score 6):

After diving into node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:268 and actually logging the error something use full came up. It happened to by my own fault it couldn't compile.

If you're facing the same problem; try to log the error from that Compilation.js:268 file;

```
if(err) {
  console.log({ err })
  return errorOrWarningAndCallback(new ModuleNotFoundError(module, err, dependencies));
}
```